# Running Gitlab in Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

I want to host a private Gitlab server on my Debian VPS. I figured using Docker would be a good setup.

I tried running Gitlab with the following code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com'
    links:
      - postgresql:postgresql
      - redis:redis
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        postgresql['enable'] = false
        gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
        gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "gitlab"
        gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "postgresql"
        gitlab_rails['db_port'] = "5432"
        gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabhq_production"
        gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
        gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
        redis['enable'] = false
        gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = 'redis'
        gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = '6379'
        external_url 'http://gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com:30080'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022
    ports:
      # both ports must match the port from external_url above
      - "30080:30080"
      # the mapped port must match ssh_port specified above.
      - "30022:22"
  # the following are hints on what volumes to mount if you want to persist data
  #  volumes:
  #    - data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:rw
  #    - data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:rw
  #    - data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:rw

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitlab
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitlab
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitlabhq_production
  # the following are hints on what volumes to mount if you want to persist data
  #  volumes:
  #    - data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:rw

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
```

Running this (*docker-compose run -d*) allows me to reach Gitlab on MYDOMAIN.com:30080, but not on gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com:30080.

Have I made an error in the configuration? Or do I need to use reverse proxies (NGINX or Traefik)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself!

- I totally forgot to add an A-record, setting gitlab.mydomain.com to point to the same IP address as @.
- I added the following block to the nginx configuration:

  ```
  upstream gitlab.mydomain.com {
      server 1.2.3.4:30080; # IP address of Docker container
  }

  server {
      server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://gitlab.mydomain.com;
      }
  }
  ```

  I use upstream because otherwise the url set in new Gitlab projects is set to the IP address, as mentioned [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14888#note_39680801).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the `hostname: gitlab.MYDOMAIN.rocks` needs to match the `external_url 'http://gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com:30080'` until the port *exactly*

So for example:

```
hostname: gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com
. . . more configuration . . .
external_url 'http://gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com:30080'
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, but that was just a typo in my post. I have set those fields correctly in my config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the subdomain gitlab in dns is pointing to the right ip? Looks like an infrastructure problem more than a docker configuration one.

Regards